# Smarty SQL request

Tags: php, sql, smarty

I have a problem with a SQL query, if my result is empty I get this error:

```
"Notice: Undefined variable: rows in..."
```

Any idea what is causing the problem?

```
function getLastInformationsChange() {
    try {
      foreach($this->pdo->query(
        "select * from INFORMATIONS where state='online' order by date DESC LIMIT 5") as $row)
      $rows[] = $row;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
      return false;
    }   
    return $rows;   
  }
```

Comment: You need to create the `$rows` variable before the foreach, so there's something to return even if there are no results.

Comment: As simple as that! Thank you, everything works.